# xcode swift is not refilling array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a script that loops through rounds of a card game, in this case I have 4 cards and 10 rounds.

When the cards array is empty I want to refill the cards array and shuffle it again and continue.

but somehow the refilling doesn't work and I get a error **Index out of range**

this is my code:

```
struct card {
    var name: String
    var val: Int
}

var allCards: [card] = []
allCards.append(card(name: "card A", val: 10))
allCards.append(card(name: "card B", val: 3))
allCards.append(card(name: "card C", val: 5))
allCards.append(card(name: "card D", val: 5))

class rounds {
    var roundNumber = 10
    var cards = allCards
    
    func playRounds() {
        switch self.roundNumber {
        case 10:
            self.cards.shuffle()
            self.roundNumber -= 1
        case 1...9:
            if cards.count == 0 {
                print("Cards shuffled")
                self.cards = allCards
                self.cards.shuffle()
            }
            self.cards.removeFirst()
            self.roundNumber -= 1
        default:
            print("End of game")
        }
    }
}

var playGame = rounds()

for _ in (0...10) {
    playGame.playRounds()
    print("Count of cards: \(playGame.cards.count)")
    print("Round: \(playGame.roundNumber)")
    print("Card name: \(playGame.cards[0].name)\n")
```

and this is my result in the debug window:

> Count of cards: 4 Round: 9 Card name: card A
>
> Count of cards: 3 Round: 8 Card name: card D
>
> Count of cards: 2 Round: 7 Card name: card B
>
> Count of cards: 1 Round: 6 Card name: card C
>
> Count of cards: 0 Round: 5 Fatal error: Index out of range: file

in the if statement in case 1...9 I have a **print("Cards Shuffled")** that I don't see in de debug window, to me it looks that there is a problem in that if statement, but I don't understand what's wrong with this.

btw. the for loop at the bottom is for testing purpose, when this script works I'll assign this script to a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access index 0 of an array if it is empty so you need to check that first before accessing it

```
if (!playGame.cards.isEmpty) {
    print("Card name: \(playGame.cards[0].name)\n")
}
```

Another way to do it is to use `first` rather than index 0

```
guard let firstCard = playGame.cards.first else { continue }
print("Card name: \(firstCard.name)\n")
```